# Cast a data frame to a 3-dimensional NumPy array because each cell contains a signal

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

my data frame contains 9 channels where every row contains a single array. casting the data frame to NumPy array gives an array with a 2-dimensional shape yet I can still access the three dimensions. this could be due to the that a second dimension type is an object. tried casting it to a float using astype() function but I get an error: setting an array element with a sequence. I want to have a data frame as a 3-dimensional array to be able to use it as a classifying model like CNN but the model reads the input as a 2 dimensional.

```
               rootdir = r'/content/gdrive/MyDrive/orderdEEG'
               df = pd.DataFrame()
               signels=[]
               labels=[]
           for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
                for file in files:
                location='{}'.format(os.path.join(subdir, file))
                c = genfromtxt(location, delimiter=',')
                c=c[1:341,0:9]
                delta=[]
                theta=[]
                low_alpha=[]
                high_alpha=[]
                low_beta=[]
                high_beta=[]
                low_gamma=[]
                high_gamma=[]
                for i in range(1,340):
                     delta.append(c[i][1])
                     theta.append(c[i][2])
                     low_alpha.append(c[i][3])
                     high_alpha.append(c[i][4])
                     low_beta.append(c[i][5])
                     high_beta.append(c[i][6])
                     low_gamma.append(c[i][7])
                     high_gamma.append(c[i][8])
                df2 = {'delta': np.array(delta).astype(np.float32), 'theta': np.array(theta).astype(np.float32), 'low_alpha': np.array(low_alpha).astype(np.float32),'high_alpha':np.array(high_alpha).astype(np.float32),'low_beta':np.array(low_beta).astype(np.float32),'high_beta':np.array(high_beta).astype(np.float32),'low_gamma':np.array(low_gamma).astype(np.float32),'high_gamma':np.array(high_gamma).astype(np.float32),'label':subdir[-1]}
  
                df=df.append(df2,ignore_index=True)
                labels.append(subdir[-1])
```

this is the way I read the CSV files containing channel columns containing the single values.
[how the data frame looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjn7r.png)

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code you are using?

Comment: The code you posted is not well formatted and may be misinterpreted.